# How do I deploy a PersistentVolume to all nodes except master nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have tried `kubectl apply` on this file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: app-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /app
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchFields:
            - key: metadata.labels.node-role.kubernetes.io/master
              operator: NotIn
              values:
                - ""
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: default-app-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

But I get:

```
The PersistentVolume "app-pv" is invalid: spec.nodeAffinity.required.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchFields[0].key: Invalid value: "metadata.labels.node-role.kubernetes.io/master": not a valid field selector key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels need to be specified with `matchExpressions`, not `matchFields`. So the `matchFields` part needs to be replaced with:

```
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
              operator: NotIn
              values:
                - ""
```